# How do I know if an message has been sent successfully when using raw WebSocket?

Tags: javascript, browser, websocket

Unlike [websocket/ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws#error-handling-best-practices) which accepts an optional `ack` callback, raw [WebSocket.prototype.send](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#send()) only accepts a single message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that *sent* != *received*... I'm assuming you want to make sure a message was **received**.

Implement `ACK`. It's super easy and it's the only way I know to make sure the message was received.

A good enough approach would attach a message ID on the client side and send that ID as part of the message (i.e. as `msgID` in a JSON). I use a timer ID because I cancel the timer when the ACK arrives and it's a good way to keep the timer data.

When the server recognizes a `msgID`, it should automatically send an ACK with the same message ID before processing the rest of the message (i.e., a JSON for `{"event":"ACK", "data":m["msgID"]}`).

If you're using binary data, you can simply append a fixed size ID at the beginning of each message (say, 8 bytes), or append a length indicator for a dynamic sized ID.

**EDIT** In reflection about Remy's comment:

Yes, using timeout IDs might be relying heavily on the way that the ID "pool" is implemented.

A safer design might prefer to avoid assumption by using a counter or some other approach.

However, it should also be noted that on all the browsers with which I tested this approach, timeout IDs are always unique.

On the [Mozilla Developer Documentation Site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), it states that:

> It is guaranteed that a timeout ID will never be reused by a subsequent call to setTimeout() or setInterval() on the same object (a window or a worker). However, different objects use separate pools of IDs.

I think this assumption is correct across the board for all browsers (subject to the ID type overflowing and resetting itself to zero).

Comment: "*I use a timer ID because I cancel the timer when the ACK arrives*" - I wouldn't use a timer ID like that. Think of what would happen if the ACK gets delayed, so you kill the timer after awhile and start a new timer on a later message, and the system decides to reuse the old timer ID, then the old ACK finally arrives. It is not hard to use a rolling number for message IDs and keep track of them with associated timer. Get an ACK, find the message ID, kill the associated timer. They don't have to be the same ID.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - That's a very good point. However, I'm not sure how applies in practice. I tested on Chrome, Safari and FireFox - none of them recycle timer handles... I think these handles don't directly reflect file descriptors, but rather use an internal design and a counter that goes on until it's type overflows (and that's a *lot* of timers)... I tested using: `existing = {}; function my_func(e) { id = window.setTimeout(my_func, 1000); console.log(id); if(existing[id]) {window.clearTimeout(id); console.log("EXISTING", id);}; existing[id] = 1;} my_func(0);`, I used different interval values.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Can you please write your version of answer. It will be helpful for beginners like us to learn from you.